# Can't add a custom field to a MenuItem in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

Is there a way through the admin UI to add a medialibrarypicker to a menuitem?  (Going for a large/visual navigation menu which will have a background image for each item).

I had added the custom field to numerous content types (such as 'content menu item') but cannot display the field.  It doesn't show up in the shape tracer tool either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

FYI, using Orchard v.1.10.1.0

Comment: Add it to the MenuItem **Part** instead

Comment: Through the dashboard or in migration code?

Comment: Doesn't mather. You asked for 'through the admin UI', so I guess through the admin UI

Comment: devqon, thanks for the response.  Correct I am using this through the Admin UI.  I had tried adding the field to the "Content Menu Item" PART (Note, a "MenuItem" part is not listed, but items such as "Content Menu Item" or "Shape Menu Item" do.

Still doesn't seem to be attached to the item when viewing on the front end.